# Accessing older versions of a file with a Cloud function within Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I [enabled versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664874/how-to-enable-and-use-file-versioning-in-firebase-storage) and accessed versions of a single json file using gsutil on a Firebase storage bucket. I am now searching how to retreive versions of that file using cloud functions and eventually allow users to get back an older version of their work if needed. I did not find any documentation on how to list versions of a file with a cloud function. Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: It might be easier if you store information about versions in a database that has more flexible querying than Cloud Storage.

Comment: I think your comment is right Doug. I am learning about firebase storage now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within Cloud Functions you'll [access Cloud Storage through the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage.Storage.html#bucket), which contains a very thin wrapper around the regular [Node.js SDK for Cloud Storage](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html).

It looks like you can pass in a [`versions` parameter](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#GetFilesOptions) to the [`getFiles` method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles).

It should be something like:

```
const result = await bucket.getFiles({ versions: true })
result.files.forEach(file => {
  console.log(file.name);
});
```

Comment: That's going to list all files in the bucket, however. I don't see an API that lets you list versions of a single file.  The only examples show gsutil and REST API, and they are also not targeting a single object. You might have to combine this with a prefix parameter in the options to get it to list versions of only a single file.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#list

Comment: Ah, in that case you can use the prefix filter to filter for a single file. Just pass the entire path of the `prefix` option: `bucket.getFiles({ prefix: 'path/to/file.jpg', versions: true })`.